# Using GetKeyNameText with special keys

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, interop

I've written a hotkey control for WPF, and want to display the friendly name to the user. For that I'm using [`GetKeyNameText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300(v=vs.85).aspx).

However, e.g. when using [`Key.MediaNextTrack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Input.Key.MediaNextTrack);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) as input, `GetKeyNameText` returns `P`, what apparently looks wrong. Can anyone help me to get the correct name for such esoteric keys?

My code does following:

1. call [`KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to get the Win32 virtual key
2. Translate the virtual key to scan code by calling [`MapVirtualKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Call `GetKeyNameText`

The complete code is this (you need to reference WindowsBase):

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var key = Key.MediaNextTrack;
            var virtualKeyFromKey = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);
            var displayString = GetLocalizedKeyStringUnsafe(virtualKeyFromKey);

            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {displayString}");
        }

        private static string GetLocalizedKeyStringUnsafe(int key) {
            // strip any modifier keys
            long keyCode = key & 0xffff;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(256);

            long scanCode = MapVirtualKey((uint) keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

            // shift the scancode to the high word
            scanCode = (scanCode << 16); // | (1 << 24);
            if (keyCode == 45 ||
                keyCode == 46 ||
                keyCode == 144 ||
                (33 <= keyCode && keyCode <= 40)) {
                // add the extended key flag
                scanCode |= 0x1000000;
            }

            GetKeyNameText((int) scanCode, sb, 256);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0x00;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetKeyNameTextW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetKeyNameText(int lParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), Out] StringBuilder str, int size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Names for these media keys are not contained in keyboard layout dll and thus not available via Win32 API. Scan code list is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#scan-codes).

Here is my wrapper around `GetKeyNameTextW` API in C++:

```cpp
// Clears keyboard buffer
// Needed to avoid side effects on other calls to ToUnicode API
// http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/10/27/5717859.html
inline void ClearKeyboardBuffer(uint16_t vkCode)
{
    std::array<wchar_t, 10> chars{};
    const uint16_t scanCode = LOWORD(::MapVirtualKeyW(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX));
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        count = ::ToUnicode(vkCode, scanCode, nullptr, chars.data(), static_cast<int>(chars.size()), 0);
    } while (count < 0);
}

std::string GetStringFromKeyPress(uint16_t scanCode)
{
    std::array<wchar_t, 10> chars{};
    const uint16_t vkCode = LOWORD(::MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX));
    std::array<uint8_t, 256> keyboardState{};

    // Turn on CapsLock to return capital letters
    keyboardState[VK_CAPITAL] = 0b00000001;

    ClearKeyboardBuffer(VK_DECIMAL);

    // For some keyboard layouts ToUnicode() API call can produce multiple chars: UTF-16 surrogate pairs or ligatures.
    // Such layouts are listed here: https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures
    int count = ::ToUnicode(vkCode, scanCode, keyboardState.data(), chars.data(), static_cast<int>(chars.size()), 0);

    ClearKeyboardBuffer(VK_DECIMAL);

    return utf8::narrow(chars.data(), std::abs(count));
}

std::string GetScanCodeName(uint16_t scanCode)
{
    static struct
    {
        uint16_t scanCode;
        const char* keyText;
    } mediaKeys[] =
    {
        { 0xe010, "Previous Track"},
        { 0xe019, "Next Track"},
        { 0xe020, "Volume Mute"},
        { 0xe021, "Launch App 2"},
        { 0xe022, "Media Play/Pause"},
        { 0xe024, "Media Stop"},
        { 0xe02e, "Volume Down"},
        { 0xe030, "Volume Up"},
        { 0xe032, "Browser Home"},
        { 0xe05e, "System Power"},
        { 0xe05f, "System Sleep"},
        { 0xe063, "System Wake"},
        { 0xe065, "Browser Search"},
        { 0xe066, "Browser Favorites"},
        { 0xe067, "Browser Refresh"},
        { 0xe068, "Browser Stop"},
        { 0xe069, "Browser Forward"},
        { 0xe06a, "Browser Back"},
        { 0xe06b, "Launch App 1"},
        { 0xe06c, "Launch Mail"},
        { 0xe06d, "Launch Media Selector"}
    };

    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(mediaKeys), std::end(mediaKeys),
        [scanCode](auto& key) { return key.scanCode == scanCode; });
    if (it != std::end(mediaKeys))
        return it->keyText;

    std::string keyText = GetStringFromKeyPress(scanCode);
    std::wstring keyTextWide = utf8::widen(keyText);
    if (!keyTextWide.empty() && !std::iswblank(keyTextWide[0]) && !std::iswcntrl(keyTextWide[0]))
    {
        return keyText;
    }

    std::array<wchar_t, 128> buffer{};
    const LPARAM lParam = MAKELPARAM(0, ((scanCode & 0xff00) ? KF_EXTENDED : 0) | (scanCode & 0xff));
    int count = ::GetKeyNameTextW(static_cast<LONG>(lParam), buffer.data(), static_cast<int>(buffer.size()));

    return utf8::narrow(buffer.data(), count);
}
```

In RawInput API you can get full scan code via such code:

```
// ...got `RAWINPUT* input` from WM_INPUT message

if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
{
    RAWKEYBOARD& keyboard = raw->data.keyboard;

    // Ignore key overrun state
    if (keyboard.MakeCode == KEYBOARD_OVERRUN_MAKE_CODE)
        return 0;

    // Ignore keys not mapped to any virtual key code
    if (keyboard.VKey >= UCHAR_MAX)
        return 0;

    BOOL keyUp = keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_BREAK;

    // Some apps may send wrong make scan codes with
    // high-order bit set (key break code).
    // Strip high-order bit and add extended scan code value.
    WORD scanCode = MAKEWORD(keyboard.MakeCode & 0x7f, ((keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E0) ? 0xe0 : ((keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E1) ? 0xe1 : 0x00)));

    if (!keyboard.MakeCode)
    {
        // Scan codes may be empty for some buttons (like multimedia buttons).
        // Try to map them from the virtual key code.
        scanCode = LOWORD(MapVirtualKey(keyboard.VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX));
    }

    std::string scanCodeName = GetScanCodeName(scanCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Virtual Keys do not contain modifiers so no need to do `&ffff`.
2. MapVirtualKey doesn't work with extended keys, which I suspect is your issue. Try using [MapVirtualKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307(v=vs.85).aspx).